# How to add support in LIferay 6.1 add message ckeditor korean language support IE11?

Tags: ckeditor, liferay, liferay-6, fckeditor

I can't  add korean language message body. in Liferay 6.1. Its seem it is older version of ckeditor issue. It is working fine in IE9, IE10. It is also working fine in chrome. It is working fine for Liferay 6.2 version as well. How can i find solution of above issue. I have attached screenshot below.
[image: Enter korean language in message board.]

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up for what you can do :

You don't need to use EXT for this. What you can do is download liferay's source code. Download patch/fixes/source-files for CKEditor from its official site (I think you might need to update the ckeditor's version if Liferay).

Put those in Liferay source's portal-web module (refer : build.xml placed in portal-web module folder to know what is getting build from where)

Create a hook and replace newly build files.

Hope it helps

Comment: Liferay best practices says to never overwrite sources.To modify portal-web (ONLY when not hookable) the suggested way is to download the Liferay sources, to prepare an EXT environment, then to deploy it. In my reply to your comment to my answer :) I already explained what are the problem using a hook. Yes, there are many ways to reach the same results, but we have to evaluate pros, cons, benefits and rescues before choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You should work in EXT, overriding the portal-web module by replacing ckeditor folder.

Another idea (not tested, but it may work) is to just override ckeditor folder directly in your installation folder (then restart your appserver): /webapps/ROOT/html/js/editor/ckeditor

In both case mind the ckeditor_diffs folder.

Comment: **"/webapps/ROOT/html/"** it self indicates, "YOU DON'T NEED EXT, YOU CAN WORKOUT WITH HOOK"

Comment: What you say MAY work, but it's not generally true. Infact it merges the old and the new contents in the new folder, and it may lead to unexpected behaviours. It's correct always if you are sure that any old editor file will be overwritten by a new one... so you have to manually diff your ckeditor installation.

Comment: The idea to replace in Tomcat is terrificant... :) if you work in this way, after a bit the ability to mantain your system will reach the absolute zero.